# Can't locate run-time error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I thought this was a very simple code designed to put borders around all the active cells in a worksheet (data will always reside in cells(1,1)). But I'm getting the infamous "run-time error 1004" and I'm stumped.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub test()
Dim myrange As Range
Dim x, y As Integer
x = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
MsgBox x
'------------------------------'
y = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
MsgBox y
Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(x, y))
   With ActiveSheet '<-- erroring here'
    .Range(myrange).Select
        With Selection.Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Doug thanks for the code unfortunately its throwing an error at "With myrange.borders"

Comment: It's better to make a comment below my answer - that way I'll be notified. Please tell me the error (below my answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me it actually errors on the next line `.Range(myrange).Select`. You've already defined myrange, and you don't need, in fact can't, qualify it.

Also, `Dim x, y As Integer`, only declares `y` as an `Integer`. `x` is declared as a `Variant`. While you're at it, you should declare them as `Longs`, which is the native VBA type.

Also, avoid using `Select` unless necessary. With that all said, here's how I'd code it:

```
Sub test()
Dim myrange As Range
Dim x As Long, y As Long
x = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
y = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(x, y))
With myrange.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is causing that. Make sure you're using just my code above - not a mix - and try it on a simple worksheet. It works fine for me, in Excel 2010.

Comment: I screwed something up when copying your code over because we are now rocking borders. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Atwp67, make sure you mark this as the answer if it solved your problem. You might want to go back to some of your other questions and do the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a shot in the dark, but I think you may want to try defining an exact sheet to use in your With statement.

```
Dim mySheet as WorkSheet
Set mySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(<name of your sheet>)
[etc etc]
```

Sometimes VBA has a hard time figuring out what the active sheet is.  I tend to use this solution because it hard codes instead of using a relative variable.  I theory you could simply put something like Sheets().Activate and use your code...  But I'm not a big fan.